# Run Current File in Interactive Window opens a preview instead

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-server

On Visual Studio Code, from time to time, this very weird behavior happens: When I click on `Run Current File in Interactive Window`, instead of opening an *Interactive Window* and running my code, it opens a *Preview* of my code. When it happens, the only solution I've found to solve the problem is to close and reopen VS Code.

When I click for the first time on `Run Current File in Interactive Window`, it works properly:
[image]

If I close the Interactive Window and click again on `Run Current File in Interactive Window`, then it opens a *Preview* of the code instead of the *Interactive Window*:
[image]

I'm using the April 2023 (version 1.78) release Visual Studio Code and I think the issue only appears when I'm using VS Code on a remote SSH server.

Comment: Are you using a Mac?
I don't have any problems on windows. But I'm guessing that the first two lines of comments are causing the error, remove them and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. Removing the script header doesn't solved the problem. I've updated the screenshots.

Comment: This might be a mistake, you can report it on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/new/choose) to get an official response.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! Here is the link: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/13499

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### EDIT:

The problem was with the **[Auto-Open Markdown Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hnw.vscode-auto-open-markdown-preview)** extension, after disabling this extension the problem was solved.

[image]

- GitHub link for this issue:

  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/13499
- GitHub issues for the **Auto-Open Markdown Preview** extension:

  https://github.com/hnw/vscode-auto-open-markdown-preview/issues/29

---

First make sure you have the full [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) installed, if you are using VS Code on a remote SSH server, [install the extension on the ssh host as well](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_managing-extensions).

In addition, you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> **Python: Restart Language Server** try to restart the language server.

At the same time, some of your personal [settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) may cause problems. You can check whether the problem can be solved by disabling extensions or deleting personal settings.

Comment: It may be due to an extension indeed. I just get a message telling me I have a deprecated extension. The name of this deprecated extension is *Python Preview*. I wonder if I installed this extension myself or if it was part of the full Python extension. I don't think I need this stuff. I'll uninstall it and see if it solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: The **Python** extension is the required extension, you can install the official version instead of the pre-release version and see if that solves the problem. Also, `Run Current File in Interactive Window` is a function provided by **Jupyter** extension.

Comment: Problem was solve by disabling the following extension: **Auto-Open Markdown Preview**.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution to your problem. I edited your comment into the answer so others can solve similar problems.